# Read JSON with a simple server Using swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, server, listener

I am trying to create a simple server that reads JSON coming in as a POST request. I found something called swifter https://github.com/glock45/swifter, but it does not seem to read JSON, only listens for an event triggered by the URL that is passed. I would Ideally like to display something in a popup box that is triggered when the correctly formatted JSON object is passed. Is there a way to do this with Swifter or any other third party frameworks? I was able to do this using node.js very easily, but would like a way to attach some UI

Comment: Is your question just about parsing json in swift? Not sure what the server has to do with it

Comment: No, I dont even need to parse it, I suppose I could take JSON out altogether. It could be plain text that is passed. An example would be a chat application. When it receives something related to the text, grab the request and the body, whether it be JSON or Text.